# Oracle SQL- Joining Tables Based on Value Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a way to add these tables together based on conditions between the table's values. Here's a visual for what I'm trying to do:

[image]

The goal is to combine the two tables with the correct corresponding sequence number, based on the Measured Depth value in table 2. The Sequence Number will correlate to the Start and End Depth from Table 1 and needs to be applied to the Measured Depth in Table 2, based on it's value and boundaries of the Start/End Depths. Is this possible? Here's my statement that I'm working with:

```
select 
      Table2.location,
      Table2.Measured_Dpth, 
      Table1.sequence_number,
      Table1.Strt_dpth, 
      Table1.end_dpth
      
     join Table2 on (Table1.location =table2.location 
     and (Table2.measured_dpth>= Table3.Strt_dpth and Table2.measured_dpth<= Table3.end_depth) )
```

**Note: Please forgive my syntax, I'm not a pro at SQL and am in the learning process- appreciate the help and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depth boundaries in table 1 are wrongly set. You can't (i.e. *shouldn't*) have the same depth set as start and end depth, so I kind of fixed that in my sample data.

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (location, seq_number, start_Depth, end_Depth) as
  3    (select 'X', 1,  100,  300 from dual union all
  4     select 'X', 2,  301,  600 from dual union all
  5     select 'X', 3,  601,  850 from dual union all
  6     select 'X', 4,  851, 1000 from dual union all
  7     select 'X', 5, 1001, 1500 from dual union all
  8     select 'X', 6, 1501, 2000 from dual
  9    ),
 10  table2 (location, measured_depth) as
 11    (select 'X',  150 from dual union all
 12     select 'X',  400 from dual union all
 13     select 'X',  850 from dual union all
 14     select 'X',  900 from dual union all
 15     select 'X', 1100 from dual union all
 16     select 'X', 1175 from dual
 17    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 18  select b.location, b.measured_depth, a.seq_number
 19  from table2 b join table1 a on a.location = b.location
 20                             and b.measured_Depth between a.start_depth and a.end_Depth;

LOCATION   MEASURED_DEPTH SEQ_NUMBER
---------- -------------- ----------
X                     150          1
X                     400          2
X                     850          3
X                     900          4
X                    1100          5
X                    1175          5

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If you can't fix boundaries, then - instead of `between` compare each depth:

```
 18     select b.location, b.measured_depth, a.seq_number
 19     from table2 b join table1 a on a.location = b.location
 20                                and b.measured_depth > a.start_Depth
 21                                and b.measured_depth <= a.end_depth;

LOCATION   MEASURED_DEPTH SEQ_NUMBER
---------- -------------- ----------
X                     150          1
X                     400          2
X                     850          3
X                     900          4
X                    1100          5
X                    1175          5

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, the 'between' call helped tremendously. But I'm having another issue- sometimes measured depths are the same values as the Start/End Depths. I don't have a small data set to be able to add the same fix that you implemented. Is there another way around that?

Comment: Yes; compare every depth alone, with e.g. ">" and "<=". See edited answer.

Comment: Perfect, this works great. Thanks so much for the help, I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Make the lower bound of the depth range non-inclusive:

```sql
SELECT t2.*, t1.sequence_number
FROM   table2 t2
       INNER JOIN table1 t1
       ON (   t1.location       =  t2.location
          AND t1.start_depth    <  t2.measured_depth
          AND t2.measured_depth <= t1.end_depth );
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (location, sequence_number, start_depth, end_depth) AS
SELECT 'X', 1,  100,  300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'X', 2,  300,  600 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'X', 3,  600,  850 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'X', 4,  850, 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'X', 5, 1000, 1500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'X', 6, 1500, 2000 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (dt, location, value, measured_depth) AS
SELECT DATE '2023-01-01', 'X', 0.01,  150 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-01-01', 'X', 0.02,  400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-01-05', 'X', 0.02,  850 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-01-06', 'X', 0.01,  900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-01-06', 'X', 0.02, 1100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-01-06', 'X', 0.02, 1175 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DT | LOCATION | VALUE | MEASURED_DEPTH | SEQUENCE_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | X | .01 | 150 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | X | .02 | 400 | 2 |
| 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | X | .02 | 850 | 3 |
| 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | X | .01 | 900 | 4 |
| 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | X | .02 | 1100 | 5 |
| 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | X | .02 | 1175 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gx7kr1QR)